# Jquery Menu and Cursor Problem

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, nav

I've been trying to change the .hover cursor on this nav menu that I found in HTMLDrive [JQuery Menu](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/239/Horizontal-Subnav-w-CSS-jQuery)

I've tried through css and jquery, for JQuery I used...

```
$("body").hover(function() { 
$(this).css({ 'cursor' : 'default'});});
```

This is just an example thought, I've been testing over all the html like nav, menu, li and ul styles

So anyone could help me and tell me what's hapenning?

By the way I'm able to edit the cursor in all the other HTML except for navigation menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS...

```
#topnav a {
    cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: umm can you test it because that just won't work for me, like i said I've been trying over all the HTML especially on my nav rules :P

Comment: I did try it with the example link you posted. Worked for me.

Comment: oooooh ok forgot to add "a" sorry for my stupidity! but sometimes I miss the simple solutions thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you should set that in the css.

if you take the link as an example you could do

```
#topnav li a:hover{cursor:default;}
```

You don't want to use javascript unless you have to. Check out this [Fiddle link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/NmMNZ/) for an example..notice the last line in the css panel

Answer (score 0):

trie this:
javascript:

```
$("#topnav a").hover(function() { 
$(this).css({ 'cursor' : 'default !important'});});

}
```

css:

```
#topnav a:hover{
   cursor:default !important;
}
```